# Copy and Paste a Cell to First Empty Row in Specific Column google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy and paste values of cell J3 from Activity Report to the first empty cell in column L.

The cell to copy is fixed, but the cell to paste in is variable.

So far the code I am using has only been able to copy the values from J3 to the last row of column L instead of the first blank row from the top. Any attempt to manipulate the destination has been unsuccessful. I was able to have it paste at the top but it kept overwriting the same cell.

```
   function copyData() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sName = ss.getSheetName();

if (sName == 'Activity Report'){
  var source = ss.getRange("Activity Report!J3");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Activity Report");
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();

  var destination = destSheet.getRange("L"+lastRow);
  destination.activate();
  source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copying data to first empty cell in Columnn L**

Copy value from `J3` to bottom of column L

```
function copyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Activity Report');
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,12).setValue(sh.getRange(3,10).getValue());
}
```

Try this:

This will put it into the very first empty cell in column L which could be the lastRow()+1 if there are no blanks.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Activity Report');
  var f=false;
  var L=sh.getRange(1,12,sh.getLastRow()+1,1).getValues().map(function(r,i){if(!f && r[0].toString().length==0){f=true;return i+1;}else{return '';}}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  sh.getRange(L,12).setValue(sh.getRange(3,10).getValue());
}
```

This uses reduce:

If nothing else it's a bit simpler.

```
function copyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Activity Report');
  var f=false;
  var L=sh.getRange(1,12,sh.getLastRow()+1,1).getValues().reduce(function(a,r,i){if(!f && r[0].toString().length==0){f=true;return a + i;}return a;},1);
  sh.getRange(L,12).setValue(sh.getRange(3,10).getValue());
}
```

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: While this is a much more optimized version of what I had, I think Ineed to use appendRow to get the result im looking for. I do not want to save J3 to the bottom the the sheet, just the first blank row in column L. Thanks

Comment: Normally when people say that they mean the row after the last row.  So do you literally mean the first empty cell in column L even if there is data above and below it?

Comment: Yes I apologize for the confusion.

My work around currently is this

`function copyDataRCCompletion() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Activity Report');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Activity Report');
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,2).setValue(sh.getRange(3,10).getValue());
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(sh2.getRange(1,5).getValue());
}`

Comment: The new script outputs Exception: cannot convert error

Comment: I'm guessiing if I knew how to use reduce better that would be a better solutiion.  So I'll play with becauseI need to get better with it anyway.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you again Cooper! Marked as answer.