# Copying specific cell data to a new sheet and filling next available row Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets file with specific data in 3 cells on Sheet 1.  When a trigger happens that I have setup, I want the data in those 3 cells copied to a specific cell on Sheet 2.  However, I need the data to fill in the next available row on Sheet 2 so that it doesn't overwrite data that is already present.  (I.e. first time data gets copied from Sheet 1 cell A1 to Sheet 2 cell A1.  Next time I want the data from Sheet 1 cell A1 to be copied to Sheet 2 cell A2...and so on).  How can I indirectly address the row, column on Sheet 2?  I do NOT want to use Google Apps Script to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a "IF" with a "ISBLANK" or something like that?

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290

I also found this guide https://www.3pieanalytics.com/excel-and-google-sheets-formulas-and-example/get-the-first-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-in-excel-and-google-sheets

Also, I understand that you do not want to use Apps script, just in case you want to give it a try, you can use this article as reference https://yagisanatode.com/2019/11/16/how-to-automatically-navigate-to-the-first-empty-row-in-a-google-sheet-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: Oh, and this one, that it does exactly what you want, but is using script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073686/copy-and-paste-a-cell-to-first-empty-row-in-specific-column-google-sheets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I don't think these tips will do what I'm looking for.  Essentially, I want to build a new table on Sheet 2, filling the next empty row each time a certain cell updates on Sheet 1.  So I'm logging the new data (statically) to make graphs with.